# FileNotFound error raised even though file does exist, permission is granted and path is correct

Tags: python, slurm, file-not-found

I am running a python script on a Sigma2 supercomputer using Slurm that references a file in another directory. Even though my user does have access to this file, and the file does exist (and the path is correct), I still get the "FileNotFound" error. See below some testing to show what I mean:

Python code:

```
dir = "/nird/projects/NS9001K/pmo033/HiddenCosts/PROCESSED_OUTPUTS/PGW/mixed/"
with Dataset(dir + 'mixed.d02.T2MEAN.rcp85.PGW2030-2060.3hrly.1996-2005.nc') as file_temperature_at_2m:
```

Outputfile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  with Dataset(dir + 'mixed.d02.T2MEAN.rcp85.PGW2030-2060.3hrly.1996-2005.nc') as file_temperature_at_2m:
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2464, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2027, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/nird/projects/NS9001K/pmo033/HiddenCosts/PROCESSED_OUTPUTS/PGW/mixed/mixed.d02.T2MEAN.rcp85.PGW2030-2060.3hrly.1996-2005.nc'
```

I have done some tests to check whether the path is correct (such as opening the path with vim), see below the results from the ls -la check:

```
ls -la /nird/projects/NS9001K/pmo033/HiddenCosts/PROCESSED_OUTPUTS/PGW/mixed/mixed.d02.T2MEAN.rcp85.PGW2030-2060.3hrly.1996-2005.nc
-rw-r--r--. 1 pmo033 ns9001k 32893224968 juni   5  2020 /nird/projects/NS9001K/pmo033/HiddenCosts/PROCESSED_OUTPUTS/PGW/mixed/mixed.d02.T2MEAN.rcp85.PGW2030-2060.3hrly.1996-2005.nc
```

Sigma2 tech support is unsure as to why this error persists. Especially since directories within my user do function. Does anyone have an idea?